# How to measure the time interval between two inputs on pin2 in Arduino?

Tags: timer, arduino, interrupt, arduino-uno

I want to measure time interval between two input pulses on pin 2 of Arduino UNO by using timer interrupt method and I have written this code but its not working properly.

This code showing only One instancw of time so I cant measure time interval.I am new in Arduino and try to make ventilator. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you !

```cpp
//Three timer interrupts
//timer setup for timer0,timer1 and timer2
//this code will enable all three arduino uno timer interrupts
//timer0 will interrupts at 2 KHz
//timer1 will interrupts at 1 Hz
//timer2 will interrupts at 8 KHz

//storage variables
boolean toggle0=0;
boolean toggle1=0;
boolean toggle2=0;

long count0=0;
long count1=0;
long count2=0;
float t=0;
float iT =0;
float fT =0;
float temp=0;
int switchPin = 2;
int switchState = 0;

void setup() {

    cli(); //stop interrupts

    //set timer0 interrupts at 2 KHz
    TCCR0A = 0;//set entire TCCR0A register to 0
    TCCR0B = 0;
    TCNT0 = 0; //initialize counter value to 0

    //set compare match register for 2KHz increments
    OCR0A = 124;//=(16x10^6)/(2000x64)-1(must be <256)
    //turn on CTC mode
    TCCR0A |=(1 << WGM01);
    //set CS01 and CS00  bits for 64 prescaler
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00);
    //enable timer compare interrupt
    TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);

    //set timer0 interrupts at 1 Hz
    TCCR1A = 0;//set entire TCCR1A register to 0
    TCCR1B = 0;
    TCNT1 = 0; //initialize counter value to 0

    //set compare match register for 1 Hz increments
    OCR1A = 15624;//=(16x10^6)/(1x1024)-1(must be <65536)
    //turn on CTC mode
    TCCR1B |=(1 << WGM12);
    //set CS12 and CS10  bits for 1024 prescaler
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10);
    //enable timer compare interrupt
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);

    //set timer0 interrupts at 8 KHz
    TCCR2A = 0;//set entire TCCR2A register to 0
    TCCR2B = 0;
    TCNT2 = 0; //initialize counter value to 0

    //set compare match register for 2KHz increments
    OCR2A = 249;//=(16x10^6)/(8000x8)-1(must be <256)
    //turn on CTC mode
    TCCR2A |=(1 << WGM21);
    //set CS21  bits for 8 prescaler
    TCCR2B |= (1 << CS21);
    //enable timer compare interrupt
    TIMSK2 |= (1 << OCIE2A);

    sei();//allow interrupts

    pinMode(switchPin,INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect){

    //timer0 interrupts 2KHz toggles pin 8
    //generate pulse wave of frequency 2KHz/2 = 1KHz
    if(toggle0){
        digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
        toggle0 = 0;
        count0++;
        t = count0/1000;
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(8,LOW);
        toggle0 = 1;
    }
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){

    //timer1 interrupts 1Hz toggles pin 8
    //generate pulse wave of frequency 1Hz/2 = 0.5Hz
    if(toggle1){
        digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
        toggle1 = 0;
        count1++;

    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(13,LOW);
        toggle1 = 1;
    }
}

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect){

    //timer2 interrupts 8KHz toggles pin 8
    //generate pulse wave of frequency 8KHz/2 = 4KHz
    if(toggle2){
        digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
        toggle2 = 0;
        count2++;

    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(9,LOW);
        toggle2 = 1;
    }
}

void loop() {

    switchState = digitalRead(switchPin);
    if ((switchState == 1) && (temp == 0)) {
        temp = 1;
    }
    if ((switchState == 1) && (temp == 1)) {
        temp = 0;
    }

    if(switchState){
        if(temp == 0) {
            iT = t;
        }
        if(temp == 1) {
            fT = t;
        }
    }

    //Serial.println(t);
    //Serial.print("Count0 :");
    //Serial.println(count0);

    //Serial.print("count1 :");
    //Serial.println(count1);

    //Serial.print("count2 :");
    //Serial.println(count2);

    // Serial.print("Time : ");
    //Serial.println(t);
    //Serial.println(switchState);
    Serial.print("First Ping Time :: ");
    Serial.println(iT);
    Serial.print("Second Ping Time :: ");
    Serial.println(fT);
    //Serial.print("Temp=");
    //Serial.println(temp);
}
```

and the output showing:

```
Second Ping Time :: 0.00
First Ping Time :: 4.00
Second Ping Time :: 0.00
First Ping Time :: 4.00
Second Ping Time :: 0.00
First Ping Time :: 4.00
Second Ping Time :: 0.00
First Ping Time :: 4.00
Second Ping Time :: 0.00
First Ping Time :: 4.00
Second Ping Time :: 0.00
First Ping Time :: 4.00
Second Ping Time :: 0.00
First Ping Time :: 4.00
Second Ping Time :: 0.00
First Ping Time :: 4.00
Second Ping Time :: 0.00
First Ping Time :: 4.00
Second Ping Time :: 0.00
First Ping Time :: 4.00
Second Ping Time :: 0.00
First Ping Time :: 4.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should not mess with timer0. Arduino uses TIMER0 for the timing. You should not change that (So as you found out it stops millis() from working). You can do whatever you want with TIMER1 and TIMER2. (although some libraries use them).
Why not use attachInterrupt()?

[Read here for How to](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/) and see [here for example code](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-interrupt-tutorial-with-examples) Sorry for not digging into your long code.

Comment: sorry!I have not much time to learn .Can you tell me please how can I modified the above code so that I shall get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem in a simpler way. Always try to divide the problem in smaller ones (not in too much!). In this case, we want:

- Start taking time when the satus changes.
- Take time.
- Stop taking time when we receive another input.

Let's start:

## Start taking time when the status changes.

If we consider that the default status of the pin is `LOW`, the code should consider that the input is `HIGH`, so this will be the first statement inside our `loop()` section. The function to read the status of a pin is `digitalRead()`. You give as a value the pin we're interested in knowing its value, and we will receive the status `HIGH` or `LOW`.

```
if (digitalRead(pin) == HIGH){
}
```

## Take time.

Now we know when to start the time, so its time to think about how we're going to take it. We can write it inside this if statement, or by creating a new function, it depends on the use you're going to make of your code. Let's implement it directly in the if statement. We can just add 1 to a variable in a loop, something like:

```
elapsedTime = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
    elapsedTime = elapsedTime + 1;
}
```

But we want to increment one after a certain time, a second. We can say to the board *hey! wait for one second after adding one*. Achieving this goal is made by waiting one second with the function `delay()`. We need to specify how much, in this case, `1000` because one second is 1000 milliseconds. More info of the function, [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/delay/). Now, our code looks like this:

```
elapsedTime = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
    elapsedTime = elapsedTime + 1;
    delay(1000);
}
```

A more common way to add one is the following: `variable++`. Another minor edit will be wait one second before adding one, because when you start the time you want to store 0, no 1. Let's re-write these lines:

```
elapsedTime = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
    delay(1000);
    elapsedTime = elapsedTime++;
}
```

## Stop taking time when we receive another input.

Now, instead of wait for this until 255 seconds, we want to do this operation until we get again to our *activated state* of our pin (HIGH). We use in this cases `while`, which means something like *hey board! do this operation until something*

```
while (digitalRead(pin) == LOW){
}
```

Now, what we write inside this function will be done until we get a false statement. Using what we wrote previously:

```
elapsedTime = 0;
while (digitalRead(pin) == LOW){
    delay(1000);
    elapsedTime = elapsedTime++;
}
```

Finally, we want to start the count when we receive the first `HIGH` input, so we wrap this inside the first line of code:

```
elapsedTime = 0;
if (digitalRead(pin) == HIGH){
    while (digitalRead(pin) == LOW){
        delay(1000);
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime++;
    }
}
```

All done! To get the result, you can print the result, or do whatever you want.
Instead of time in seconds, you can measure any unit, just change the value inside `delay()` to any you want. For example, if we want to measure milliseconds, it will be `delay(1)`.